# Alterar nomes das colunas utilizadas para guardar o timestamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Quando armazeno ou edito dados em uma tabela pelo **laravel** este cria um `timestamp` que utiliza os campos `created_at` e `updated_at`

Porém tenho que armazenar os dados em uma tabela compartilhada com outro sistema, e esta utiliza outra nomenclatura para armazenar estes dados.

Sem ser a solução de setar o `timestamp = false` e na hora de armazenar eu mesmo adicionar o `timestamp` lá.

No próprio `model` tem como eu setar o nome do `creted_at` e `updated_at` para outro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei este exemplo na [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) e deu certo

> If you need to customize the names of the columns used to store the timestamps, you may set the  `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` constants in your model:
>
> ```
> class Flight extends Model
> {
>     const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
>     const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
> }
> ```